# Why is github pages not deploying my react app?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I know there have been a lot of posts like this, and after browsing through all of them, I have not come up with a solution. I moved my index.html file to the root and have a  tag that says "test" which prints out, but nothing else does. Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My React Application</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="src/App.js"></script>
  <h1>test</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my repo: https://github.com/alexeum31/Youtube-Searcher

I've been trying all kinds of things for a while, help would be appreciated!